# How to reduce SSH2 "loading" time

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I'm using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) to execute a command on my unix server via SSH2, the command is only doing ctrl + c (exiting the script, I don't really know how to say that, sorry) after like 15 seconds and so when I want to do a `file_get_contents("api.php?param=test");` in PHP the page is loading during like 15 seconds (it's finishing loading after the script is finish/done).

So I would like to execute the command, and directly write something like "ok" after. I don't want this loading time.

PS: I'm doing it like that : https://hastebin.com/hoyulazeha.xml

Sorry, I'm not English.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Does it take a long time to login to the server via command line? Have you checked the ssh config on the server to disable unnecessary DNS and GSSAPI (if you don't need them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `$ssh -> setTimeout(1);` before `$ssh -> exec($command);` and it's stopping loading after 1 second, and the script is executing correctly.